# Handling space in the file name, FOR loop, batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, input, whitespace

I am trying to find all the MP3 files in a given directory, then export it to a file, before trying to use the contents of the file as an input.

All the instances of file copy are working fine, except for the file locations which contain spaces. How should I address this in my current code. Please refer to the screenshot below

Contents of my MP3_Location.txt file are:

```
C:\Test\asdad.MP3
C:\Test\New folder\werwer.MP3
C:\Test\OneDrive - Backup\asdasdasdad.MP3
```

[image: File location with spaces not working]

```
REM Exporting the location of the MP3 file in a given directory 
DIR /s/b "C:\Test\*.MP3" >> C:\Software\MP3_Location.txt

REM Trying to copy the files based on the previous Output 
FOR /F %%G IN (C:\Software\MP3_Location.txt) DO c:\windows\system32\xcopy 
"%%G" C:\Software\MP3\ /Y
```

Edit 1: Trying to use Delims now, as suggested (perhaps not using it correctly)

```
REM Exporting the location of the MP3 file in a given directory
DIR /s/b "C:\Test\*.MP3" >> C:\Software\MP3_Location.txt

REM Trying to copy the files
FOR /F %%G "tokens=* delims=" IN (C:\Software\MP3_Location.txt) DO c:\windows\system32\xcopy "%%G" C:\Software\MP3\ /Y
```

Comment: You need to use the delims option to tell the FOR command to not use any delimiters.

Comment: @squashman Tried delims in the loop, but it is still not working.

Comment: You know you don't have to make the file list first.  You can use the `FOR /R` command to iterate the files `FOR /R C:\TEST %%G IN (*.mp3) do` or use a `FOR /F` command and use the `DIR` command inside that: `FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /s *.mp3') do ....`.

Comment: Your first attempt at using DELIMS is incorrect because you need the OPTIONS before the for variable. The syntax for the `FOR /F` is clearly defined in the help file: `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN (file-set) DO`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Squashman, apologies was a little stressed and missed on the basic thing.Grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used the command

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN
```